# Android Nougat not Showing Calendar as spinner view

Tags: android, android-calendar

I facing problem in Nougat (API 24) that Calendar is not showing as spinner However it work proper till (API 23).
I am using this style

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item> 
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: try changing parent theme to holo light or holo dark

Answer (score 0):

Try changing parent theme to holo as in place of material theme.

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dark">
```

Comment: Hi Karan Mer it do't work for Nought Calendar does not shown spinner view

Comment: try adding this to xml `datePickerMode="spinner"`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I find out is to inflate it through XML. I have a `DialogFragment` and here is the code that works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
            style="@style/Cerhis.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Base" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

---

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends BaseDialogFragment {

    ...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.date_picker_dialog, container, false);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(defaultDate != null)
            c.setTime(defaultDate);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        binding.datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                onDateSet(datePicker, year, month, day);
            }
        });

        if (!futurePossible)
            binding.datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

        binding.ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismissWithUserInteraction();
                if (mListeners != null) {
                    for (DatePickerListener listener : mListeners)
                        listener.onDateSet(selectedDate, dialogId);
                }
            }
        });

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext(), R.style.Cerhis_Dialog);
        if(dialog.getWindow() != null)
            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    ...
}
```